# Use return values only in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action **Map** in my Controller **Address**. In the Action Method I get all the addresses like this:

```
public ActionResult Map()
{
    var model = this.UnitOfWork.AddressRepository.Get();
    return View(model);
}
```

My Address Model looks like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public Decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    public Int32 StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public Int32 RegionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to use the latitude and the longitude in the javascript part of the page.
How can I do this?

I've tried to the following:

```
<script>
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    // at this stage the model javascript variable represents the JSON encoded
    // value of your server side model so that you can access all it's properties:
    alert(model.length);
</script>
```

But I got this error:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Address_F9A550E3CE9AB1122FFC2E0A154FBDCAF8648B6FBCF91A81E35459DCA2E075AA'.
```

Comment: This is why we use separate view models.

Comment: Sooo you have a circular dependency. Where do you construct your `Model` object? I'm guessing it's related to the `ICollection<Person> Persons`. When you create an `Address` object, does this create a `Person` as well?

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Person` class? I think you may have a circular reference if Person has an Address property.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic). Your JSON serializer is unable circular references which are legit in JavaScript

Comment: Sound familiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935331/json-deserialization-throws-circular-reference-only-in-live-build ?

Comment: One more question with jQuery tag not related to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it says you have a circular reference somewhere in your mode, but you can set the json parser with options to avoid circular references.

Better would be to parse your mode into a separate viewmodel:

```
var model = this.UnitOfWork.AddressRepository.Get().Select(m => new ViewModel{
    Latitude  = m.Latitude,
    Longitude  = m.Longitude,
});
return View(model);
```

This way you only expose the information to the client that is needed.

If you need only a few parameters you might be better of with something like this:

```
<script>
    var lat = @Model.Latitude;
    var lon = @Model.Longitude;
    // at this stage the model javascript variable represents the JSON encoded
    // value of your server side model so that you can access all it's properties:
    alert(lat);
</script>
```

Comment: Then I get this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[App.Models.Address,ReUzze.Models.MapViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ReUzze.Models.MapViewModel'.

Comment: Then change your model in your view to the new viewmodel. My code is just an example.